# How to convert blank into null in ssis

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssis

I am extracting data from excel in `ssis`. One of the excel column contain `blank` values. so i need to replace `blank` value with null otherwise my package is going to fail. 
Any suggessions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might also want to check the option to Keep Null values on both source and destination connection (if available)

Comment: This is not the point! Point is how to deal with or replace NULL values. I have tried your suggestion but it is not working. There should be Expression to replace Empty values with NULL or user defined values.

Comment: Well, i guess you're right. If this is a Flat file, there's an option on the Flat File Source to retain null values. Having this enabled as well as the option "Keep NULL values" on destination connection (like OLEDB) might eliminate the need to replace it using Derived column transform.

Comment: Hmm!!! Well I have Excel as a Source. Excel contains some empty cells and when I load them in DB, it gives NULL. I have tried to use expression (Conditional Split) but it is not working. I will paste my error as soon as possible.

Comment: This never works if we have "<space>" only in the data field.

Answer (score 63):

In DataFlow use DerivedColumn component.

Replace your column and in expression put this line of code

`ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : ColumnName`

It will make sure to return null if column is empty

Comment: Can we use this expression without having derived column?

Comment: Can we replace the same column multiple times in a row without using another DerivedColumn or a more complex formula ?

Answer (score 12):

Did you tried something like (under assumption datatype is of string/varchar) :

```
LEN(TRIM([ColumnName]))==0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : [ColumnName]
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's not string it's date we cannot use ltrim for date...... :(

Comment: This actually worked. I was using DT_STR and that failed, despite the Data Type showing as string [DT_STR].

Answer (score 2):

Fix for the above problem :::::

Source and destination must checked with the option allow null values and it will work.

Comment: In my case I was using a Flat File Source and the option under 'Connection Manager' of the left are was a checkbox 'Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow'

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar instance where I wanted to replace a string in a date column to NULL, and I used the following code:

LEN(your_data) < 2 ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : your_data

In this case, the string had a length of only 1.  I then used the data conversion transformation to get it to the dt_dbtimestamp type.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Derived Column component, and a conditional expression. Since this is a conditional statement data types will need to be the same to create a Boolean result.

Try using this:

```
ColumnName == (DT_DATE)"" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use REPLACE function in String Functions

Example: REPLACE(columnNmae,"  ","0")

First Param: column name
Second Param: the existing value that you want to replace it
Third Param: the value that you replace in the second param