# SSIS: Specify NULL in conditional expression (e.g in Derived column)

Tags: ssis

all
I already solved my issue with perfect solution by Alexander Fedorenko(c)
([How to convert blank into null in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053240/how-to-convert-blank-into-null-in-ssis)) which shows how conditionally replace nothing "" with NULL.

I just want to understand completely how it work in SSIS. In my setup I have source column Varchar(8) and Destination Column float.
And it works perfectly with this sample:

```
`ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : ColumnName
```

Is this the only way to specify NULL having DT_WSTR,50, my destination is float i.e. DT_R4 in SSIS, I tried to use this with DT_R4 and it's failed, so looks like it tied to Source column.
I don't understand I can't use this, I do add new column in derived box like:
`enter code here`ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_R4) : ColumnName
    ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_R4) : ColumnName

Thanks much
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that `ColumnName`'s data type is string. At least, this comparison, `ColumnName == ""` implies it is a string type (unicode or ascii)

So, when you are doing

```
ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_R4) : ColumnName
```

SSIS is going to see that as

```
(condition) ? (generate a NULL that is typed as float) : (some string type)
```

Since a string and float are incompatible, that's not going to work. Instead, you'll need to force the cast on the ColumnName as well

```
ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_R4) : (DT_R4) ColumnName
```

I have run into situations where the above still generates incompatibility errors and so I end up casting all of it to the target type

```
(DT_R4) (ColumnName == "" ? NULL(DT_R4) : (DT_R4) ColumnName)
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for explanation. Best. M